# why in Java floating-point calculation is slower than C

Tags: java, c, floating-point

I'm wondering and researching in floating point calculations why Java is slower than C. Actually some algorithms doesn't affect too much. C is faster than Java 3 or 4 times. But in floating point calculation there is a huge difference. Can anybody help me?

Comment: C is native code, Java runs in the JVM.

Comment: actually some algorithms doesn't affect too much. C is faster than Java 3 or 4 times. But in floating point calculation there is abig difference. Im wondering that.

Comment: Modern java compiles to native code at runtime and should not be much slower at actually performing the calculation.  Its means of doing something with the result and getting it back to you probably still involve much more overhead that the simplest options in C.  Tough to comment without examples!  If you're just starting up java, doing a small number of calculations, then stopping it again, it *is* running as interpreted byte code and will be comparatively very slow at everything.

Comment: @asumanelif: What's a "big difference"? Can you post an example, please?

Comment: Are you using Float or float?  Changing code from Float to float is a big speedup.  Can you give some example of the types of algorithms you are using that are hugely slower in Java?

Comment: Please show the specific floating point calculation for which you say there is a huge difference. Until you do the answers will be pure speculation. For example, here's a floating point calculation where the difference doesn't seem to be "huge" http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64/performance.php?test=nbody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers for middle level languages such as C are smart enough to exploit [vectorization](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401611) and other techniques to provide speed for the same piece of functionality as compared to interpreters for high level languages such as Java who need to a one extra layer of converting the platform independent  byte code to platform specific assembly.

Having said that Virtual machine comes with its own overheads for maintaining the state of your program for garbage collection and other activities such as Thread scheduling within the JVM.

To be more specific [JAVA floating point operations hurt everyone](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf).

> Java’s floating-point arithmetic is blighted by five gratuitous
>   mistakes:
>
> 1. Linguistically legislated exact reproducibility is at best mere wishful thinking.
> 2. Of two traditional policies for mixed precision evaluation, Java chose the worse.
> 3. Infinities and NaNs unleashed without the protection of floating-point traps and flags mandated by IEEE Standards 754/854
>      belie Java’s claim to robustness.
> 4. Every programmer’s prospects for success are diminished by Java’s refusal to grant access to capabilities built into over 95% of today's
>      floating-point hardware.
> 5. Java has rejected even mildly disciplined infix operator overloading, without which extensions to arithmetic with everyday
>      mathematical types like complex numbers, intervals, matrices,
>      geometrical objects and arbitrarily high precision become extremely
>      inconvenient.

Comment: If the authors of that article weren't so cutesy with their language I might bother to read it.  But when they write "parody of puffery promoting  100% Pure Java" I have to wonder if their main goal is really to stir up controversy and make a name for themselves.

Comment: @user949300 these are Berkeley guys who were trying to bash Java back in the days. :-) so the aversion is pertinent from their natural use of words :D

Comment: Isn't this (at least partially) outdated? This was written before [Strictfp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/strictfp) was introduced.

Comment: @Banthar I don't disagree with you. That's the reason in above comment i said "..guys who **were** trying to bash Java **back in the days**"

Answer (score -2):

C is compiled and ends up as machine language.

Java is compiled to byte code and then *interpreted* by the Java Virtual Machine.

Interpreted will be slower than assembled code by definition (you can think of interpreted as line by line assembly .. repeatedly e.g., if inside a loop)

Comment: Java code ends up as machine language too. Modern JVMs have just-in-time compilers.

Comment: Yet Java runs generally slower than C .. any idea why? I'm not arguing, just curious.

Comment: There are many reasons why it's generally slower. I don't see reasons why floating point calculations would be slow.

Comment: There's lots of different ways to do math in machine code. As others have pointed out whether x87 instructions vs MMX vs using functions (using either method) could significantly impact performance.